# Two HttpHandlers handling same file type

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

In my new job, they have already written an httphandler to handle all the .aspx files, and they are not using asp.net's httphandler. Now, I want to use asp.net's regular .aspx httphandler for some web pages (.aspx files) in the project and the other pages need to be handled using their customized httphandler, i.e., 2 httphandlers for same file type (.aspx), how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place your pages in their own directory, you can remove the custom handlers and add the normal ones in a `web.config` file placed in the same directory.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx) document on MSDN, in particular the section about `Configuration Inheritance`.

---

Update:

Another option is to use different file extensions for the custom handler and for the normal ones and register the handlers accordingly.

Comment: if I place the pages that need to be handled by the regular httphandler in a separate folder, and add a separate web.config file (configured to handle .aspx files using regular http handler), to that folder... it works!! my question was, what if we want to handle some web pages with the customized handler, and some with the regular handler?

Comment: @Gokulnath - Then you can't have them both in the same folder. Unless you decide to use different file extensions for the different handlers.

Comment: got it, thanks!! between, say suppose I change the extension of the files that need to handled by regular handler to ".abcd", I know we have to register the extension to aspnet isapi filer in IIS, what if we are using VS's web server, is there a way to configure it?

Comment: @Gokulnath - Probably not. But you can use [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) instead of the dev web server. It is free.